# How to display text from a text file in labels which are created dynamically depending on number of lines in the text file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Below is my code. I have a text file "D:\1.txt" which contains some text in lines. i want to display each line as a label in a Tabcontrol Tabpage.
But using this code I am only able to create the first line as a label. The other lines are not displayed.THIS code is triggered during a form load.

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\1.txt"
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
            Dim label1 As New Label
            label1.Text = line
            TabPage2.Controls.Add(label1)
        Next
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the location for your labels within the loop - otherwise they'll all be created with the default location and therefore be in the same place.

Maybe add `label1.Height` to a variable each time round the loop and set `label1.Top` to that each time.